# If $\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=a(x-y)$, then what is $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question states:

> If $\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=a(x-y)$, then what is $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

The options are:

> 1. $$\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1-y^2}}$$
> 2. $$\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}}$$
> 3. $$\frac{1-x^2}{1-y^2}$$
> 4. $$\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2}$$

I tried differentiating the entire expression:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac{-2y}{2\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{dy}{dx} &= a(1-\frac{dy}{dx}) \\
a + \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &= \frac{dy}{dx}(a-\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= (a+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})(a-\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}})^{-1}
\end{align}$$
I am not sure how to proceed now. Is there a better approach? Is it advisable to use my approach?

Comment: Instead of doing this way bring everything to one side and try partial differentiation , saves a lot of time

Comment: @SujithZis I can do nothing but suggest that you add an answer. Also, could you add some nice reference texts on this topic?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a question *about* self learning, though.

Comment: Try substitute x=sinA and y=sinB and simplify and proceed with differentiation .

Comment: @SujithZis: You do realize that $y$ is a function of $x$ and that this problem is about implicit differentiation, do you? I am saying this because I can hardly see how your previous two comments fit into the general theory of the differential calculus of implicit functions.

Comment: @AlexM. I was planning to give him a generalised approach without giving any fuzz about resubstitution .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is absolutely fine and the result that you have obtained is correct. If you handed me a homework like this I would be satisfied, since it is clear that you have understood the procedure of implicit differentiation.

Still, the problem is somewhat pedantic and asks you to do a final superfluous simplification: note that $a$ is absent from all of the available options, therefore express $a$ as $\dfrac {\sqrt{1-x^2} + \sqrt{1-y^2}} {x-y}$ and replace it in your own result. After a number of elementary algebraic simplifications you will obtain $\dfrac {\sqrt{1-y^2}} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, which is option 2.

Answer (score 2):

> As stated in the comments this is actually a wee-bit lengthier and
>   hence not recommended.

Since i always try to resort to trigonometric substitutions whenever fractional powers are involved I'm gonna attempt this by substituting $x=sinA$ and $y=sinB$

$cosA +cosB=a(sinA-sinB)$

$2cos\frac{(A+B)}{2} \times cos\frac{(A-B)}{2} =a\times 2Cos\frac{(A+B)}{2}\times Sin\frac{(A-B)}{2}$

$cot\frac{(A-B)}{2} =a$

$A-B=2cot^{-1}a$

Magically reducing it to

$sin^{-1}x-sin^{-1}y =2cot^{-1}a$

Now differentiate…

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}} \times \frac{dy}{dx}=0$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$

> If you are preparing for JEE ADV i would recommend practising differential calculus book by cengage , and for theory i would recommend Differential Calculus by AmitMAgarwal

Comment: While your approach is clearly original and correct, I would have a hard time considering it simpler than the other two posted above. In fact, I consider it quite convoluted, obscuring the underlying ideas.

Comment: I believe a bit more explanation would suffice. :-)

Comment: Lol rethinking about it i guess you are right this is pretty lengthier . Well i guess I'm pretty used to using trigonometric substitutions wherever fractional powers are involved .

Comment: One must also know that is the substitution correct? Yes, because since we have a square root, then term inside must be positive, therefore $x^{2}∈\left[0,1\right]$ and thus since the range of sine does cover this, it is a viable substiution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's supposed to be a way to eliminate $a$ from the formula.

Let's try to tackle the term $a+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ first, using the fact that
$$a(x-y) = \sqrt{1-x^2} + \sqrt{1-y^2}.$$

In order to avoid dealing with a lot of fractions, I would
multiply $a + \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ by the factor $x-y$ from the equation
and by the denominator $\sqrt{1-x^2}$.
Then
\begin{align}
\left(a + \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)(x-y)\sqrt{1-x^2}
&= a(x-y)\sqrt{1-x^2} + x(x - y) \\
&= (\sqrt{1-x^2} + \sqrt{1-y^2}) \sqrt{1-x^2} + x^2 - xy \\
&= 1 - x^2 + \sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-x^2} + x^2 - xy \\
&= 1 - xy + \sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2} \\
\end{align}

Next, work out the value of
$$
\left(a - \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right)(x-y)\sqrt{1-y^2}
$$
in a similar manner to get an expression in $x$ and $y$ only.
Compare the two results and see if that allows you to simplify your expression to one of the desired answers.

Comment: This is the same basic idea as the answer by Alex M. (posted at almost the same time); it just does some of the algebraic manipulations before the substitution rather than after. If you finish it as suggested in the last paragraph it comes fairly quickly to the same result. Alex M.'s answer is a more direct approach and _should_ be ranked higher (as it is at this time).